# Saving a list of strings on Database (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm studying SQL and I'm trying to save in a table USER a list of TAGS (which are strings) of interests. What's the best way to do that? Should I save all tags as PRIMARY KEY in a new table? should them have their on PRIMARY KEY and than I need to compare the tag to see if its already exists? I totally don't know what's the best solution for it.

Should be something like:

```
}
  Name: "John",
  interests: ['Cars', 'Motorbike', 'Programming']
}
```

Comment: Look up `many to many` relationships. That is what you're looking for. Don't save a list of values in the database. You'll regret it.

Comment: The topic you're looking for is called [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  The object is to stricture your database according to the rules of relations.

Comment: thanks guys, you helped me a lot

Comment: It depends on how you want to use the tags. Do you need to search them? If not, you could save them as json. MySQL is set up for that. I would use Neville's method though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dfundako says in the comment, this is an example of a many-to-many relationship. In your case, one user may have many tags, and a tag may belong to many users.

The common way to model this is an intersection table.

```
Users
-------
User_id (pk)
name
...

Tags
-----
tag_id (pk)
tag_content

user_tags
---------
user_id (pk)
tag_id (pk)
```

It's usually not a good idea to use the tag content as a primary key - primary keys should be unique and immutable. What happens if someone wants to change the tag name, e.g. because of a typo? So, the _id columns in the example above would be artificial keys.

Comment: On this case, inside the USER_TAGS table, both of attributes would be the PRIMARY KEY ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend three tables:

```
create table users (
    user_id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    . . .
);

create table interests (
    interest_id int auto_increment primary key,
    interest varchar(255),
    . . .
);

create table user_interests (
    user_interest_id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int not null,
    interest_id int not null,
    foreign key (person_id) references users(user_id),
    foreign key (interest_id) references interests(interest_id),
    unique (user_id, interest_id)
);
```

The `. . .` is for additional columns about the respective entities.

Why do you want a separate table for `interests`?  Because you want to be sure that people are referring to the same thing.  You wouldn't want one person to write "Programming" and another to use "Coding" to mean the same thing.